# What parts are used in this unicorn from Lego Ideas?

Tags: part-identification, ideas

I feel like I should be able to find all these pieces and here I am asking.

I am trying to gather a list of pieces to buy to build this model found on [LEGO Ideas](https://ideas.lego.com/projects/d2750297-702b-4c8b-8a02-005558036f77). It is this Unicorn with articulating legs and neck.

The problem is, I don't know how to articulate the words needed to find some of these pieces.

Let me share a modified screenshot of the current piece I'm stuck on.  However if you know the fire pieces on the neck, or want to just make my whole list I'd love that.

I also am not sure what pieces make up the joint between the legs and the body. They look kinda like this Technic 1 x 2 piece ([85943](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=85943&idColor=85#T=C&C=85)) piece but it is at least 2 x 2, I think.

I also am not sure what pieces make up the neck joint to the body but in the pictures on the LEGO Ideas page, it looks like that it can move too.

[image: Highlight 2 parts I'm not sure about.]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mane seems to be based on [64647 Minifgure Plume Feather Triple Compact](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64647) in either trans-orange or trans-neon orange colour; each plume is mounted on a [85861 1 x 1 round plate wih open stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=85861).

The hooves are [47458 1 x 2 x 2/3 Curved Slope Wing End](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47458).

The leg joints seem to be tow-ball joints. See parts [22890 1x2 plate with tow-ball](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=22890), [14418 1x2 plate with tow-ball socket on end](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=14418), and [14704 1x2 plate with tow-ball socket on side](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=14704).

Comment: It looks like [Technic, Brick Modified 2 x 2 with Ball Socket and Axle Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92013&name=Technic,%20Brick%20Modified%202%20x%202%20with%20Ball%20Socket%20Wide%20and%20Axle%20Hole&category=%5BTechnic,%20Brick%5D#T=C) is used to connect the legs to the body

Comment: I have recreated this to the best of my ability on bricklinks' "Studio+" app.  I will share it as soon as they allow it to be published.

Comment: https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/design.page?idModel=260209